# How to solve NoClassDefFoundError on Heroku using maven?

Tags: java, maven, heroku, noclassdeffounderror, ormlite

I am trying to deploy my app on heroku and i am getting a **NoClassDefFoundError** while calling the index.html page. The Error log looks like this:

```
    2018-11-04T19:13:02.080531+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with 
    command `java $JAVA_OPTS -cp target/classes:target/dependency/* 
    com.treslines.server.Server`

    2018-11-04T19:13:05.913978+00:00 app[web.1]: Setting 
    JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS defaults based on dyno size. Custom settings will 
    override them.

    2018-11-04T19:13:05.926232+00:00 app[web.1]: Picked up 
    JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Xmx300m -Xss512k -XX:CICompilerCount=2 
    -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8

    2018-11-04T19:13:06.250733+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: A JNI error has 
    occurred, please check your installation and try again

    2018-11-04T19:13:06.250788+00:00 app[web.1]: Exception in thread 
    "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/j256/ormlite/support
    /ConnectionSource

    2018-11-04T19:13:06.250796+00:00 app[web.1]: at 
    java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)

    2018-11-04T19:13:06.250799+00:00 app[web.1]: at 
    java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)

    2018-11-04T19:13:06.250801+00:00 app[web.1]: at 
    java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)

    2018-11-04T19:13:06.250808+00:00 app[web.1]: at 
    java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)

    2018-11-04T19:13:06.250810+00:00 app[web.1]: at 
    java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)

    2018-11-04T19:13:06.250812+00:00 app[web.1]: at ... 7 more
```

So I understand the error and i looked up in my **target/dependency** folder locally and there are all dependencies of the missing class inside of **ormlite-core-5.1** and **ormlite-jdbc-5.1** libraries.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jZtQZ.png)

So far so good. My proc file on heroku looks like this:

```
    web: java $JAVA_OPTS -cp target/classes:target/dependency/* com.treslines.server.Server
```

In my maven pom.xml, i have those configurations:

...

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.j256.ormlite</groupId>
        <artifactId>ormlite-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.j256.ormlite</groupId>
        <artifactId>ormlite-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>5.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

...

```
    <configuration>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <!-- This tells Maven to include all dependencies -->
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>com.treslines.server.Server</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
```

...

```
    <plugin>
            <groupId>com.heroku.sdk</groupId>
            <artifactId>heroku-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.4.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <jdkVersion>1.8</jdkVersion>
                <!-- Use your own application name >>> heroku enforces lowcase names -->
                <appName>stocknews</appName>
                <processTypes>
                    <!-- Tell Heroku how to launch your application -->
                    <web>java $JAVA_OPTS -cp target/classes:target/dependency/* com.treslines.server.Server</web>
                </processTypes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

The code runs locally on localhost like a charm. I pushed the code to heroku successfully, everything runs just fine, maven build success and so on. But when i call **heroku open** on the command cli or type the url on the browser, the **NoClassDefFoundError** occurs.

**Does anyone have an idea how to solve it?** Is there a way to access the deployed code on heroku to see what was deployed effectivelly?

Comment: Did you looked into source of corresponding class? Can you show its content?

Comment: Looks like some static stuff could not be loaded

Comment: Hi @StrangerintheQ , yes, the **ConnectionSource** is just an interface of ormlite. The implementation of if is **JdbcConnectionSource** and does not have any static thing on it. Only a connectionProxyFactory which is initialized by the framework automatically over a factory in case this variable is null. What astonishes me is that it works perfectly locally. I am assuming that this class was extensivelly tested. I am trying now to see what was effectivelly deployed on heroku.

Comment: What command do you use to run the app locally?

Comment: @codefinger localy i use **run as JavaApplication** normally. (on localhost)

Answer (score 1):

Begin by updating the heroku-maven-plugin. You're on 0.4.4, but the latest is 2.0.6:

```
<version>2.0.6</version>
```

Comment: Hi @codefinger, i did it. But i think that's still not the problem. I figured out something related to my proc.file. I used now:

        **web: java $JAVA_OPTS -cp target/stocknews-1.0.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar com.treslines.server.Server**

pointing to the packaged jar. Now i am getting the erro related to the property file which was located in the **java/main/resources** It says: **can't find property file** I think it is because heroku takes it and put it outside of it. Looking inside of the structure of the package jar, i saw it. I just can't understand, why heroku does it that way!

Comment: I have a property reader referencing a property file inside of **java/main/resources** The problem now is that those files are now located outside of this package. I am trying to figure out how to make it visible again to the main program inside of the packaged jar file. Any ideia?

Answer (score 1):

**RESOLVED**

Resolution: Both tutorials on spark java and on heroku are outdated. The websites said you should have a processType like this:

...

```
    <web>java $JAVA_OPTS -cp target/classes:target/dependency/* com.treslines.server.Server</web>
```

...

However, while deploying it on Heroku, the **maven-assembly-plugin** i had, didn't create the **target/dependecy** folder as used to. To solve this problem, you must include the missing dependencies like this:

```
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1</version>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                  <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                  <outputDirectory>target/dependency/</outputDirectory>
                  <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
                  <overWriteSnapshots>false</overWriteSnapshots>
                  <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
                </configuration>
              </execution>
            </executions>
          </plugin>
```

when you deploy your app on heroku, there is also a command line to see and inspect the deployed artefacts. **heroku run bash** After that you can type **ls** to see if your deployed package is correct.

Than you just have to push it to your heroku master by typing: **git push heroku master** Maven will re-deploy it, but that time it will append all project dependencies to the folder **target/dependency** as expected. Now you can call **heroku open** to browse your app.